# Keyboard shortcut for a particular keyboard key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Is there a possibility in macOS Catalina 10.15 to set a keyboard shortcut for a particular key, for example the "r" key?

Comment: If you have shortcut assigned what key would you press in order to get letter “r”?

Comment: This feels very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Please ask us about the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than how to implement your assumed solution.

Comment: Do you have a broken keyboard?

Comment: I agree with @Tetsujin… this feels like a gaming issue your’ee trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

In System Preferences, use Keyboard:Text to replace "r" with another character.

Or if the behavior is only wanted in Word for example then Word has a text replacement function as well.

Comment: That works, but not in all possible writing cases, for example in some HTML input text in some web pages it works well, in the macOS Notes app it also works, in the search field in Finder too. It does not work in the address bar of the Chrome Browser, for example, nor in some input or textarea fields on different web pages.